# Set Zend response into a variable

Tags: zend-framework, request, response

I have an action that returns a JSON. I need to call it from another controller and  I need to get this response into a variable to parse the JSON.

I've tried:

```
private function makeListFromUrl($menu)
{
    $req = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
    $req->setRequestUri('/module/controller/get.json/');

    $res = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();
    $dis = $this->getFrontController()->dispatch($req, $res);

    $dis->dispatch($req, $res);

    $json = $res->getBody();

    return Zend_Json::decode($json);
}
```

But this code causes the front controller to render the action, overriding the actual action. I just want to make a request, get the response into a variable, while leaving the actual request untouched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have a simple solution to this, not sure if it's the best, but worked very well.

```
$actionHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_Action();

$var = $actionHelper->action('action', 'controller', 'module', $params);
```

same way you'd do inside the view, but in the controller.

i hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set returnResponse(true) for the FrontController to send the response back.

```
private function makeListFromUrl($menu)
{
    $req = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
    $req->setRequestUri('/module/controller/get.json/');

    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->returnResponse(true);
    $response = $front->dispatch($requestObj);

    $json = $res->getBody();

    return Zend_Json::decode($json);
}
```